# Opening two webservers via one ps1 script

Tags: python, powershell

I've tried running the following, via PowerShell, in a single ps1 script in the hope of two localservers opening on different ports - only 8080 is opened:

```
cd "\\blah\Statistics\Reporting\D3\walkthroughs\letsMakeABarChart" 
python -m http.server 8080

cd "\\foo\data_science\20161002a_d3js\examples" 
python -m http.server 8000
```

Can I adjust it so both get opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first python invoke probably *doesn't return* so you could use the `Start-Job` cmdlet:

```
$job1 = start-job -scriptblock {
    cd "\\blah\Statistics\Reporting\D3\walkthroughs\letsMakeABarChart" 
    python -m http.server 8080    
}

$job2 = start-job -scriptblock { 
    cd "\\foo\data_science\20161002a_d3js\examples" 
    python -m http.server 8000 
} 

# Wait until both web servers terminates:
Wait-Job -Job ($job1, $job2)
```

Comment: thanks Martin - almost there - ps window pops up and both cmds run but then the ps window disappears - so I think both webservers are running for a short time and then they are gone!

Comment: Ah, forgot that you use a script to execute it. I edited my answer - just use the `Wait-Job` cmdlet to wait until both jobs finished.

Comment: lovely - guessing this is more tricky - both servers are now running but ps is not giving me any feedback about stack traces etc ... can we amend this so I still get some feedback? (just a "nice-to-have" but would be a cool touch)

Comment: Yes, take a look at the Receive-Job cmdlet to retrieve the output of a running job.